# Dynamic RMI method generation

Tags: java, dynamic, classloader, rmi

I have to develop client and server component which are communicate via RMI.

```
public interface Test {
  public String getInformation();
}

public class TestImpl implements Test {

    public String getInformation() {
        return “Hello”;
    }
}
```

This Test interface is available to execute in RMI client side but in RMI server not available this  Test interface and TestImpl classes but all these class names, method names , parameters, return type are available as a metadata (saved in DB). I need virtually generate Test and TestImpl class in server side and inject these to RMI server. How do I do this?

Comment: Try Spring with its dependency injection engine.  You've reinvented a lot of wheels here.

Comment: Define. Define 'dynamic RMI method generation'. Define 'virtually generate'. Define why you apparently need to test services that don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **generate** the RMI server class from class names, method names , parameter types, return types etc either stored in DB or somehow else , you can use any of several well-known byte-code instrumentation tools like [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/)(most popular), [Javassist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/) or [BCEL](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/)(embedded version is also available in JDK since at least version 1.5).
(I am not sure what does "virtual" generation mean and what is the difference between "virtual" and "non-virtual" class generation). 
The **injection**, if you mean the registering with java.rmi.registry.Registry like  [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/hello/hello-world.html), of an instance of generated class is trivial and does not differ from an "injection" of any other RMI server.

As a side note : It seems you have quite unusual design. Storing class names, method names etc in the DB is one thing. Another one is that all this information is defined in your case on the client side, while usually it's other way around.
Anyway, if you need to go with this design, then, as an option, you could consider storing in the DB the interfaces in the compiled(binary) form of .class files instead of the text definitions of class names, method names etc. In this case you won't need to mess up with byte-code generation, and could use plain Java reflection Proxy/InvocationHandler or, at worst, simple [CGLIB](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/) proxy.